# python, how to modify a dict attribute of a class instance

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I have an instance that has a dict. how can i modify the dict in a function, by the key from the dict?

```
class myclass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mydict = {'number':0}

def myfunction(foo):
    foo.mydict[number] += 10 #<- doesnt work gives me 'global name number not defined' 


instance = myclass()
myfunction(instance)
```

hope you can help me,
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this has nothing to do with it being a class attribute:

```
foo.mydict['number'] += 10
```

The key need to be a string.

Comment: bwaaaa. but ofcourse, 4:20 am here, might be better to call it a night... thx a lot

Answer (score 1):

`number` should be a string

```
foo.mydict['number'] += 10
```